# SQL same join in two columns with different values

Tags: sql, join

I don't know what is the best way to do this

**FIGHT**

```
Fighter_ID1 | Fighter_ID2
```

**FIGHTERS**

```
ID | Fighter
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Fighter1 | Fighter2
```

I want to join the column `fighter` of the table `FIGHTERS` with the two columns in table `FIGHT`..

It can be an stupid question but I don't know how to do this in a correctly way

Sorry about my English and thanks

Comment: Do you want to join the results one after another or in two separate columns in the same result?

Comment: de output have 2 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  F1.Fighter as Fighter1,
        F2.Fighter as Fighter2
FROM    FIGHT
        INNER JOIN FIGHTERS as F1 ON FIGHT.Fighter_ID1 = F1.ID
        INNER JOIN FIGTHERS as F2 ON FIGHT.Fighter_ID2 = F2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to join on the table twice.

```
SELECT fs1.Fighter as Fighter1, fs2.Fighter as Figther2
FROM Fight f
INNER JOIN Fighters fs1
    ON f.Fighter_ID1 = fs1.id
INNER JOIN Fighters fs2
    ON f.Fighter_ID2 = fs2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
    select f1.name, f2.name -- pick any column you like
    from FIGHT f -- from here we join both fighters by id
    join FIGHTER f1 on f.fighter_id1 = f1.id
    join FIGHTER f2 on f.fighter_id2 = f2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you would have 2 fighters for each fight you will want to alias your table. I am typing this directly here so I cannot guarantee it is 100% accurate but it should look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FIGHT 
  INNER JOIN FIGHTERS AS F1 ON F1.ID = Fighter_ID1
  INNER JOIN FIGHTERS AS F2 ON F2.ID = Fighter_ID2
```

Then you can get the fighter names using F1.Fighter and F2.Fighter as your fields.